# Why component "Sample Texture 2D" in Unity Shaders distorts my sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have [this texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlGvd.png) and when I add it to the "Sample texture 2d" component, it is drawn where there is simply no sprite (transparent background). It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCn1o.png). With the help of a shader, I did outline. And because of this, when I connect outline with texture, [they blend where there is no texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWWXL.png). How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Shader Graph's "Sample Texture 2D" Node doesn't preview the alpha channel (transparency) correctly, although it does keep the alpha value (since it returns a vec4, rather than a vec3).

It's unclear what you want to do here. If you want to make the outline be a solid color, rather than using the texture, use a "Blend" node rather than the "Add" node you're currently using, with the "Overlay" mode selected.

Answer (score 0):

Many image editors save the background colour even for full alpha values. If the texture isn't set to sprite Unity displays the hidden "artist smears" areas.

If the preview bugs you, you can reexport the image with GIMP and save with "Save background color" disabled. Unity will display alpha as black, which might be more pleasant to look at.